# Sum between array values

Tags: c++, sum

I'm learning c++ by myself and I'm currently having trouble making the sum between array values (if >0 else <0).

This is what I've been doing (bilIniziale is my array):

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    int sum = 0;
    if(bilIniziale[i] > 0) {
        sum+=bilIniziale[i];
    }else{
       sum+=bilIniziale[i];
    }
}
```

I also tried with `sum = sum + bilIniziale[i];`
but no difference.

In the terminal at the moment its only shows the element >0 or <0 but without summing between them; how can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean? You're just summing any value that is non-zero, which is the same as summing all values. Did you want to sum the _absolute_ value or something? Of course, the main problem is that `sum` is a local variable in your loop, so it is reset to zero every time and not visible outside the loop.

Comment: Your test doesn't make sense, because you're doing the same thing whether it's true or false.

Comment: What I need is to find in the array the values that are <0 and sum them; viceversa for >0.

Comment: the result of the IF is correct because it's only showing the elements of array >0 and else viceversa so the cycle and ifelse statement seems right, but I need to sum them

Comment: If you want two sums, you can't store them in just one variable, can you? And you can't declare a variable inside a loop if you need its value after the loop.

Comment: You need two sum variables (ex: sum_lower and sum_upper). And according to the test you add on the right sum.

Comment: Okay, so 2 variables, make actual sense, didnt think of it.

Comment: @CGi03 I LOVE YOU THNKS

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the variable `sum` to persist outside of the loop you need to move the declaration outside of the loop

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    if(bilIniziale[i] > 0) {
        sum+=bilIniziale[i];
    }else{
       sum+=bilIniziale[i];
    }
}
```

In your version a new `sum` variable gets created and set to zero **each time** round the loop.

Also as stated in the comment above. The `if` statement makes no sense because you do the same thing whether it's true or false. So the above can be simplified

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sum += bilIniziale[i];
}
```

**EDIT**

So it seems the requirement is to make two sums, one of the negative elements the other of the positive elements. So we need two variables, one for each sum. Something like this

```
int positive_sum = 0;
int negative_sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if (bilIniziale[i] > 0) {
        positive_sum += bilIniziale[i];
    } else {
        negative_sum += bilIniziale[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. The solution u gave me it's correct, to have the result of all the elements of the Array. But I was asking how to sum the elements <0 and >0, differentiate between them.

Comment: @Natao OK I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), you might do:

```
const int positive_sum =
    std::accumulate(std::begin(bilIniziale), std::end(bilIniziale), 0,
                    [](int acc, int value){ return value > 0 ? acc + value : acc; });
const int negative_sum =
    std::accumulate(std::begin(bilIniziale), std::end(bilIniziale), 0,
                    [](int acc, int value){ return value < 0 ? acc + value : acc; });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Wo67cfbbP)

With regular for-range loop, it would be:

```
int positive_sum = 0;
int negative_sum = 0;
for (auto value : bilIniziale) {
    if (value < 0) {
        negative_sum += value;
    } else { // NO special case for value == 0 as += 0 is noop
        positive_sum += value;
    }
}
```